# Print Variable containing backslashes

Tags: bash, echo, escape-characters, printf

I have something like this:

```
A=$(curl https://mysite.com)
```

and the curl request returns the string `\"Hello World\"`.
When I now want to print `A` to the console using one of:

```
echo "$A"
printf '%s' "$A"
```

the `\` dissappear and it just says `"Hello World"`. What can I do to get `\"Hello World\"` on the console?

Comment: If `printf '%s' "$A"` doesn't show backslashes, then they're not there. What's the output of `typeset -p A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `printf '%s' "$A"` doesn't show any backslash then they're not there. You can check with `curl https://mysite.com` alone.

Maybe you were confused by the output of:

```
bash-5.0$ typeset -p A
declare -- A="\"Hello World\""
```

That's bash outputting shell code that could be used to define that `$A` variable. In the syntax of the shell language, the `\` is there to escape the following `"` to tell the shell that that `"` is part of the data and not the closing quote.

It could also have output:

```
declare -- A='"Hello World"'
```

Which does just same (and is safer). Or `A=\"Hello\ World\"` or `$'"Hello World"'`, etc which are other forms of quoting in the shell language syntax.